# How do I make animation nodes drive the vertices of my object?

Tags: animation, audio, animation-nodes

I recently got into animation nodes in Blender, and want to know if I can drive the vertices of an object using sound.

I found this example here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtD5UQE5Xj0

However, I can't find some of the nodes in the latest version of animation nodes.

I'm trying to make a sound file adjust the vertices of a circle with the method shown in the video.

Answer (score 1):

Best to start by breaking down your problem:
- You want a node tree setup to control vertices of mesh
- Sound to drive the vertices

Check AN Templates for those two:
* Simple Sound Controller
* Random Vertices Offset

The YouTube demo is cool, but if node is missing, you probably can try to look for similar node.

[image]

Try a simpler setup first like maybe have a LINE and try to drive the vertices of the line by using sound.